# php how to differentiate between 0 or 1 and boolean

Tags: php, variables, boolean

In some cases the key which is returned by array_search() is 0 or 1. When I use this return value in an if-statement, php interprets it as boolean.. but I want it to be interpreted as a string. How can i do this?

example:

```
$array=array('abc','a','b');

$returnvalue=array_search('abc',$array); // will be 0

if($returnvalue!=false){
statement // right now, this will not be executed
}
```

thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: replace `$returnvalue!=false` with `$returnvalue !== false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use type safe comparisons:

```
if ($returnvalue !== false)
```

The same is also supported for ==, with ===:

```
if ($returnvalue === false)
{
    // not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`==` compare for value

`===` compare for value and data type

See:

```
$array = array('abc','a','b');
$returnvalue = array_search('abc', $array); // will be 0

if($returnvalue == false){
    // Executed
    var_dump($returnvalue);
}

if($returnvalue === false){
    // Not executed
    var_dump($returnvalue);
}
```